# log4j2 new objectMessageAsJsonObject problem

Tags: java, json, logging, log4j2, spring-webflux

I got a problem with this configuration and I'm trying to identify if the error comes from a json serialization (using **lombok** and **jackson**), compatibility with libraries or something else.
I'm trying to write a custom object in the *message* field as json with log4j2 and I read that **objectMessageAsJsonObject** will help me, this is my **logj2.xml**

```
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <JSONLayout properties="true" compact="true" eventEol="true" objectMessageAsJsonObject="true">
                <KeyValuePair key="guid" value="${ctx:guid}"/>
                <KeyValuePair key="ip" value="${ctx:x-forwarded-for}"/>
                <KeyValuePair key="user-agent" value="${ctx:user-agent}"/>
                <KeyValuePair key="host" value="${ctx:host}"/>
            </JSONLayout>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com" level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

This is my custom object

```
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class EventLog {

  private String service;
  private String method;
  private String event;
  private String eventType;
  private String level;
  private Object information;
  private Long elapsedTime;
  private String sessionId;
  private String identification;
  private String code;
  private String message;
}
```

My pom dependencies

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
<properties>
<spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR8</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

And the result I'm given

```
{"instant":{"epochSecond":1603722213,"nanoOfSecond":172284000},"thread":"reactor-http-nio-3","level":"DEBUG","loggerName":"com.reactive.aspect.LoggableAspect","message":"EventLog(service=com.controllers.ControlListController, method=verifyControlList, event=null, eventType=REQUEST, level=LEVEL_001, information=[Ljava.lang.Object;@5fa99897, elapsedTime=1603722209217, sessionId=null, identification=null, code=null, message=null)","endOfBatch":false,"loggerFqcn":"org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger","contextMap":{"X-B3-SpanId":"aadb80928473e529","X-B3-TraceId":"5f96dbe1d99a094aaadb80928473e529","X-Span-Export":"true","host":"localhost:8080","spanExportable":"true","spanId":"aadb80928473e529","traceId":"5f96dbe1d99a094aaadb80928473e529","user-agent":"PostmanRuntime/7.26.5"},"threadId":28,"threadPriority":5,"guid":"${ctx:guid}","ip":"${ctx:x-forwarded-for}","user-agent":"PostmanRuntime/7.26.5","host":"localhost:8080"}
```

Expected result

```
{"instant":{"epochSecond":1603722213,"nanoOfSecond":172284000},"thread":"reactor-http-nio-3","level":"DEBUG","loggerName":"com.reactive.aspect.LoggableAspect","message":"{custom object as json}","endOfBatch":false,"loggerFqcn":"org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger","contextMap":{"X-B3-SpanId":"aadb80928473e529","X-B3-TraceId":"5f96dbe1d99a094aaadb80928473e529","X-Span-Export":"true","host":"localhost:8080","spanExportable":"true","spanId":"aadb80928473e529","traceId":"5f96dbe1d99a094aaadb80928473e529","user-agent":"PostmanRuntime/7.26.5"},"threadId":28,"threadPriority":5,"guid":"${ctx:guid}","ip":"${ctx:x-forwarded-for}","user-agent":"PostmanRuntime/7.26.5","host":"localhost:8080"}
```

The way I'm trying to write the log is by an aspect on methods.

```
@Around("@annotation(loggable)")
  public Object logMethodEntryExit(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, Loggable loggable) throws Throwable {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String className = pjp.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName();
    String methodName = pjp.getSignature().getName();
    Object information = pjp.getArgs();
    log.debug(EventLog.builder()
        .method(methodName)
        .service(className)
        .elapsedTime(start)
        .information(information)
        .eventType(REQUEST.name())
        .level(loggable.level().name())
        .build());

    Mono<Object> result = (Mono<Object>) pjp.proceed();
    long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    return result.doOnNext(element -> log.debug(EventLog.builder()
        .method(methodName)
        .service(className)
        .elapsedTime(elapsedTime)
        .information(element)
        .eventType(RESPONSE.name())
        .level(loggable.level().name())
        .build()));
  }
```

And the json is never shown, please a little help with this

Answer (score 0):

encountered similar issue on similar setup - downgrading org.springframework.cloud to Hoxton.SR6 (and org.springframework.boot to 2.3.0.RELEASE) solved it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but having the same problem downgrading these dependencies.
Tried with 2.4.2 for org.springframework.boot and 2020.0.1 org.springframework.cloud and still doesn't work